# Script for reinstalling apps on macOS with brew cask

Tags: macos, homebrew

I looked around for this and couldn't find it. Before venturing into coding it, I thought I'd ask…

I regularly update my mac via terminal with `brew`, `macports`, `pip`, `yarn`, etc. So I started reinstalling my apps via `brew cask` so they get regularly updated. It's pretty mechanical, and I'm sure there's a way to automate it. All it'd need to do is `ls` the apps in the `Applications` folder, compare it to the `brew cask list`, and `brew cask --force install`  those not already there. A more rounded script would use `brew search` and ask the user to pick and confirm if results were ambivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted!

```
cd /Applications
brew cask list -1 > apps.txt
brew search --casks > casks.txt
for f in *.app do
    if grep -Fixq ${${f%.*}// /-} casks.txt && ! grep -Fixq ${${f%.*}// /-} apps.txt
        then HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew cask install --force ${${f%.*}// /-}
    fi
done
```